# CSS translate with keyframe animation and scale on hover not working together

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, keyframe

I'm relatively new to CSS. I saw a lot of similar topics but I couldn't find a solution to this problem so I'll ask away.

I'm trying to create a photobanner with a keyframe animation where the images scroll to the left and scale with img:hover. The translation transform works fine and the scale transform works fine however, the latter only works if I remove the css for the keyframe animation. How can I get both transformation to work at the same time?

My CSS is as follows:

```
.photobannerContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.photobanner {
    height: 480px;
    width: 8000px; /* To contain all the images end-to-end. */
}

.photobanner img {
    height:100%;

    transition: all .2s ease;

    /*If I remove these lines then the scale transformation will work.*/
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}

@keyframes bannermove {
    0% { 
        transform: translateX(0); 
    }    
    100% { 
        transform: translateX(-3726px); 
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
    0% { 
        -moz-transform: translateX(0); 
    }    
    100% { 
        -moz-transform: translateX(-3726px); 
    }
}



@-webkit-keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3726px);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: translateX(-3726px);
    }
}



@-o-keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: translateX(-3726px);
    }
}
```

The HTML is set up as follows:

```
<div class="photobannerContainer">
<div class="photobanner">

<img src="url"/>

<img src="url"/>

<img src="url"/>

<img src="url"/>

<img src="url"/>

<img src="url"/>

<img src="url"/>

<img src="url"/>

<img src="url"/>

</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i have the problem today,and i dont know the reason too,but i solved it by add a extra `div` tag out side `animation-div` tag,and put `transition` in the outside `div`
like:

html

```
<div class="extra-div">
  <div class="animation-div">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.extra-div{
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.extra-div:hover{
 transform: scale(1.9);
}
.animation-div {
    animation: myAnime 0.2s ease-out

}
```